# Group elements of array of objects Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I've been trying to group elements with the same values in the array for hours but I'm going nowhere

Array:

```
list = [
    {id: "0", created_at: "foo1", value: "35"},
    {id: "1", created_at: "foo1", value: "26"},
    {id: "2", created_at: "foo", value: "13"},
    {id: "3", created_at: "foo1", value: "11"},
    {id: "4", created_at: "foo", value: "11"},
    {id: "5", created_at: "foo1", value: "16"},
    {id: "6", created_at: "foo", value: "26"},
    {id: "7", created_at: "foo1", value: "13"},
    {id: "8", created_at: "foo1", value: "16"}
];
```

The result I'm trying to get is:

```
var result = [
    [
        {id: "0", created_at: "foo1", value: "35"}
    ],
    [
        {id: "1", created_at: "foo1", value: "26"},
        {id: "6", created_at: "foo", value: "26"}
    ],
    [
        {id: "2", created_at: "foo", value: "13"},
        {id: "7", created_at: "foo1", value: "13"}
    ],
    [
        {id: "3", created_at: "foo1", value: "11"},
        {id: "4", created_at: "foo", value: "11"}
    ],
    [
        {id: "5", created_at: "foo1", value: "16"},
        {id: "8", created_at: "foo1", value: "16"}
    ]         
];
```

any ideas how to get that?  thanks in advance.

Note: I'm working with angular 5.

Comment: Can you post what you've been trying so we have something to work off of to help you?

Comment: Many many examples of this in a search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+group+array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're considering using Lodash for this, you could use **[`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy)** for this:

```js
var list = [
    {id: "0", created_at: "foo1", value: "35"},
    {id: "1", created_at: "foo1", value: "26"},
    {id: "2", created_at: "foo", value: "13"},
    {id: "3", created_at: "foo1", value: "11"},
    {id: "4", created_at: "foo", value: "11"},
    {id: "5", created_at: "foo1", value: "16"},
    {id: "6", created_at: "foo", value: "26"},
    {id: "7", created_at: "foo1", value: "13"},
    {id: "8", created_at: "foo1", value: "16"}
];

var response = _.groupBy(list, 'value');

console.log(response);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unless OP specifies, you should assume the answer should not introduce a new library. You can comment and ask them if using lodash is ok though, but if they can't/don't want to use it, this answer is not useful to them or future readers.

Comment: @SterlingArcher, sorry about that. I'll sure keep that in mind. :)

Comment: Not a problem! No need to apologize at all :)